# Django Facebook timeout

Tags: python, django, django-facebook

Since I updated to the newest version of django facebook I get this error:

```
TypeError at /facebook/connect/
open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

Here is the full trackback:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_facebook/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  92.                 get_persistent_graph(request, redirect_uri=current_uri)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_facebook/api.py" in get_persistent_graph
  62.         graph = get_facebook_graph(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_facebook/api.py" in get_facebook_graph
  161.                             code, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/open_facebook/api.py" in convert_code
  251.         response = cls.request('oauth/access_token', **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/open_facebook/api.py" in request
  75.         response = cls._request(url, post_data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/open_facebook/api.py" in _request
  110.                                                 timeout=timeout)

Exception Type: TypeError at /facebook/connect/
Exception Value: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've "fixed" this by removing the timeout param from here:

/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/open_facebook/api.py

The timeout param is right below the comment saying this param could be left out for older python versions.

Answer (score 0):

think you should try upgrading the Python version you're using  (or better yet, use virtualenv!)

looks like you're using Python 2.5 which is pretty old, so maybe you're getting that error because the library is relying on that timeout= keyword argument which was probably added in 2.6 or 2.7 etc.

From `https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/blob/master/open_facebook/api.py#L92`, looks like its calling open() on a urllib2.OpenerDirector, so probably that timeout keyword arg was added there ^ at some point

Comment: I'm working on remote server with 0% chances of getting updated. So that wasn't the option. I'm also aware that the version of Python i'm using is old and that the param is added in version 2.6.

Comment: hmm in case you got shell access (just not root), I would definitley check out virtualenv:   basically it makes an isolated Python install which you have full acess to change and stuff etc.